# E-Mail showing all "TO" addresses in e-mail even w/ addresses in Bcc. Outlook 2010

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I have a client who sends e-mails to a list of a 1000 people everyday. Even though I've added list to the Bcc when sending e-mails. Alot of people are telling me that they have to scroll down through the 1000+ email addresses before they can read the body.

I'm using Outlook 2010 on Win 7. What can I do about this?

Comment: To start: Asses which email client(s) the recipients with the problem are using.  What kind of email account is this set up as in Outlook (POP, IMAP, Exchange)? Depending on the mail server and mail client, BCC recipients can/will be allowed to see other BCC recipients.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a limitation set by the system administrators to avoid spamming. While I've read that Outlook has no limitations, I've also seen lots of questions regarding this. One of the most informative posts [I could find.](http://its.uiowa.edu/support/article/3767) Seems as if they used a size limitation therein, instead of a number of contacts. I would ask the Exchange Administrator about this. If that's the case, I would create multiple lists and concatenate them in the BCC field.